# How to protect AWS API gateway URL from unauthorized access?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I want to host my static website in AWS  S3. But it contains "contact us" page which is for sending emails. When the user clicks the submit button it sends the request to AWS API gateway, API gateway triggers the lambda function; the lambda function sends the mail to Admin.

But it has some problem . when we host the website at server we can use captcha to prevent the submit request automation and fraudulent activities . in this case the anybody can misuse (sending more request by passing a query string in the URL ) my API gateway URL who know it.

So my question is **how to know that the submit request is requested from my website only** and **is there any way to use instead of Captcha**?.

Comment: You can achieve the same via Googe Captcha since for each request, it requires to creation a session with the Captcha which is validated from the API.  Why is it to use something else than the captcha?

Comment: we are not going to use any server , then how captcha will be validated

Comment: Using a API Gateway and Lambda where you validate the captcha. The other option is to use CloudFront and AWS WAF for rate based blocking.

Comment: can we use google captcha in our website which is hosted in AWS S3 bucket

Comment: Only with S3 you can't do it, you can display it in a static page but needs to validate from the backend. You can use API Gateway and Lambda as a backend to validate the captcha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googles reCAPTCHA looks fairly simple to integrate -

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro
which breaks into -

1. Validate user with captcha (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display)
2. Validate the response (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify)

This can easily be achieved with API gateway endpoints and lambda (your secret will be in lambda [Maybe as env variable], site key will go in s3 static site)

Anyway why not design your own verification mechanism (If you really want to do stuff yourself :))? Ask for users phone number before letting them submit (or on submit..). Then invoke a API gateway endpoint which gets this number and sends an otp via SNS. Once user verifies this otp (another api gateway call) then only send the admin email (do further processing). You can store this otp is some rds with validated boolean flag. You don't have to worry about these API gateway endpoints since they are really for authentication only and are scaled automatically with cloud front.

Comment: thank you , but i have little doubt. i am using api gateway url to pass the form data by query string and use back end python lambda function to send mail. if I add the google captcha in my form . how to pass the data by query string in api gateway url which is entered by the user in google captcha

Comment: You don't return the query string entered by user. Google APIs will verify it for you  and give you the user response token. This is provided by reCAPTCHA, verifying the user on your site. Send it to lambda and from their verify if this response is correct - https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

Comment: thanks you , finally I have completed my task with aws lambda to validate a google captcha, its very useful. thank you once gain

Answer (score 2):

**Validate reCAPTCHA using API Gateway and Lambda**

For Contact Forms on serverless SPA sites on S3 static sites, I use AngularJS with the "angular-recaptcha" service (https://github.com/VividCortex/angular-recaptcha), though you can use any way of getting and POSTing the recaptcha value.

On the Backend you can use API Gateway which calls a Lambda function to validate the recaptcha value and do something. Using NodeJS and Recaptcha2 (https://www.npmjs.com/package/recaptcha2) to validate the token.

```
var reCAPTCHA = require('recaptcha2')

module.exports.sendemail = (event, context, callback) => {

    // parse the data that was sent from API Gateway
    var eventData = JSON.parse(event.body);

    // Prepare the recaptcha connection to Google
    var recaptcha = new reCAPTCHA({
      siteKey: process.env.RECAPTCHA_KEY,
      secretKey: process.env.RECAPTCHA_SECRET
    })

    // Validate the recaptcha value
    recaptcha.validate(eventData.recaptcha)
        .then(function(){
            // validated ok
            console.log("ReCaptcha Valid")


            ... DO STUFF HERE ...


        })
        .catch(function(errorCodes){

            // invalid recaptcha
            console.log("ReCaptcha Not Valid")

            // translate error codes to human readable text
            console.log(recaptcha.translateErrors(errorCodes));

            // send a fail message with cors headers back to the UI
            var response = {
                statusCode: 500,
                headers: {
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({"message":"Error: Invalid Recaptcha"})
            }
            callback(null, response);
        });
};
```

**Example Templated Emails using Handlebars and SES**

As a bonus, here is some code I reuse for sending emails using html/text templates:

- Handlebars to inject values to the template SES to send the email.
- Make sure that you have set up SES with your domain name, and permissioned the Lambda to "ses:SendEmail" and "ses:SendEmailRaw".
- Add the environment variables when deploying the function, this makes the code reusable and keeps the secrets out of the source code.
- I highly recommend using the Serverless Framework to deploy your serverless applications. https://serverless.com

Works a treat for me :)

```
'use strict';

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var ses = new AWS.SES();
var reCAPTCHA = require('recaptcha2')
var fs = require('fs');
var Handlebars = require('handlebars');

module.exports.sendemail = (event, context, callback) => {

    // parse the data that was sent from API Gateway
    var eventData = JSON.parse(event.body);

    // Prepare the recaptcha connection to Google
    var recaptcha = new reCAPTCHA({
      siteKey: process.env.RECAPTCHA_KEY,
      secretKey: process.env.RECAPTCHA_SECRET
    })

    // Validate the recaptcha value
    recaptcha.validate(eventData.recaptcha)
        .then(function(){
            // validated ok
            console.log("reCAPTCHA Valid")

            // Read the HTML template from the package root
            fs.readFile('./contact/email_template.html', function (err, emailHtmlTemplate) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Unable to load HTML Template");
                    throw err;
                }
                // Read the TEXT template from the package root
                fs.readFile('./contact/email_template.txt', function (err, emailTextTemplate) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("Unable to load TEXT Template");
                        throw err;
                    }

                    // Gather data to be injected to the templates
                    var emailData = {
                        "websiteaddress": process.env.WEBSITEADDRESS,
                        "websitename": process.env.WEBSITENAME,
                        "content": null,
                        "email": process.env.EMAIL_TO,
                        "event": eventData
                    };

                    // Use Handlebars to compile the template and inject values into the title (used in subject and body of email)
                    var templateTitle = Handlebars.compile(process.env.EMAIL_TITLE);
                    var titleText = templateTitle(emailData);
                    console.log(titleText);

                    // Add title to the values object
                    emailData.title = titleText;

                    // Use Handlebars to compile email plaintext body
                    var templateText = Handlebars.compile(emailTextTemplate.toString());
                    var bodyText = templateText(emailData);
                    console.log(bodyText);

                    // Use Handlebars to compile email html body
                    var templateHtml = Handlebars.compile(emailHtmlTemplate.toString());
                    var bodyHtml = templateHtml(emailData);
                    console.log(bodyHtml);

                    // Prepare the SES payload
                    var params = {
                        Destination: {
                            ToAddresses: [
                                process.env.EMAIL_TO
                            ]
                        },
                        Message: {
                            Body: {
                                Text: {
                                    Data: bodyText,
                                    Charset: 'UTF-8'
                                },
                                Html: {
                                    Data: bodyHtml
                                },
                            },
                            Subject: {
                                Data: titleText,
                                Charset: 'UTF-8'
                            }
                        },
                        Source: process.env.EMAIL_FROM
                    }
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(params,null,4));

                    // Send SES Email
                    ses.sendEmail(params, function(err,data){
                        if(err) {
                            console.log(err,err.stack); // error

                            // Handle SES send errors
                            var response = {
                                statusCode: 500,
                                headers: {
                                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
                                    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true
                                },
                                body: JSON.stringify({"message":"Error: Unable to Send Message"})
                            }
                            callback(null, response);
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log(data); // success

                            // SES send was successful
                            var response = {
                                statusCode: 200,
                                headers: {
                                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
                                    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true
                                },
                                body: JSON.stringify({"message":"Message Sent"})
                            }
                            callback(null, response);
                        }
                  });

              }); //end of load text template
          }); //end of load html template


      })
      .catch(function(errorCodes){

          // invalid recaptcha
          console.log("reCAPTCHA Not Valid")

          // translate error codes to human readable text
          console.log(recaptcha.translateErrors(errorCodes));

          // send a fail message with cors headers back to the UI
          var response = {
              statusCode: 500,
              headers: {
                  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
                  "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true
              },
              body: JSON.stringify({"message":"Error: Invalid Recaptcha"})
          }
          callback(null, response);
     });
 };
```

Edit: fixed syntax error

Comment: thank you , but i have little doubt. i am using api gateway url to pass the form data by query string and use back end python lambda function to send mail. if I add the google captcha in my form . how to pass the data by query string in api gateway url which is entered by the user in google captcha

Comment: in php we do this for store in a variable $data = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']   how to do the same in javascript

Comment: `var eventData = JSON.parse(event.body);` gets the input variables, then `eventData.recaptcha` is the recaptcha value. The same as `eventData.contactFormMessageFromUser` or 'eventData.contactFormEmailAddressFromUser`

Comment: For your example, you would use `eventData.['g-recaptcha-response']` to get the post value for reCAPTCHA. (the change of format as variable names with hyphens can not be accessed in the same way, should be avoided really).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Referer header on http. It is set by browser.

Comment: how referrer header useful for my scenario

Comment: just see the header Referrer in the HttpRequest you are getting after submit is hit.. I feel Referrer will give you your website page